# Back Button to Return to a Previous App using Ng-Cordova

Tags: cordova, redirect, ionic-framework, ngcordova

We are creating two apps in ng-Cordova. The first app is called `FFriends` and the second one is `SaveData.We`. We need a "back" button to return to a previous App. Like this:
[image]

Above image have `Back to Safari`. We need `Back to FFriends` like that. So we added `LSAPlicationQueriesSchemes` like this:
 [image]
But there's still no `Back to FFriends` option. What are we doing wrong?

Please guide to us.

Comment: Please try to put a specific issue. "Please guide us" is not a proper question to ask at SO, it will end up as "too broad" and will be put on hold. Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @YakovL thanks for advice.